# Python print api specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

```
import requests

url = "https://sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com/"

querystring = {"sign":"aquarius","love":"today"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "sds",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text])
```

Hi , this is my code

Output is

```
{"date_range": "Jan 20 - Feb 18", "current_date": "June 12, 2021", "description": "Nobody seems to have their lives ordered as well as you do today -- but what else is new? You should see if you can find the time to reach out and help those closest to you, but don't break your back!", "compatibility": "Taurus", "mood": "Thoughtful", "color": "Yellow", "lucky_number": "97", "lucky_time": "8am"}
```

i want to print "date_range" or "`compatibility`" . how to print ?

Answer (score 1):

request allows us to get a json decoded response by doing

```
data = response.json()
```

Then you can access it as dictionary in python.

```
print(data["data_range"])
```

Relevant documentation: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content